# Salesforce: Issues in removing the entire child node in an xml

Tags: apex, xml, xmlparsing, xmlnode

I have an xml , and I tried to remove an entire child nodes using the xml DOM process. Even i use the remove child method , the result says true but if i print the dom it still holds that child element. Below is the XML structure

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CustomResponse xmlns="http://p3.secure.asp/2006/04/data">
        <businessTypes>
            <fullName>Standard Process</fullName>
            <active>true</active>
            <classifiedvalues>
                <name>Business Area</name>
                <values>
                    <segName>ESK</segname>
                    <default>false</default>
                </values>
                <values>
                    <segname>TIS</segname>
                    <default>True</default>
                </values>
            </classifiedvalues>
 <classifiedvalues>
                <name>Business Source</name>
                <values>
                    <segName>Online</segname>
                    <default>false</default>
                </values>
                <values>
                    <segname>Retail</segname>
                    <default>True</default>
                </values>
            </classifiedvalues>
        </businessTypes>
    </CustomResponse>
```

I wanted to remove the entire classifiedvalues from the xml

Below is the apex code , I was trying

```
    FileData = the above xml

Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
  doc.load(fileData.toString());
  Dom.XMLNode root = doc.getRootElement();  
Dom.XMLNode l1 = root.getChildElement('businessTypes', 'http://p3.secure.asp/2006/04/data');
Dom.XMLNode l2 = l1.getChildElement('classifiedvalues','http://p3.secure.asp/2006/04/data');
Boolean remove = root.removeChild(l2);
system.debug('#####'+remove);
system.debug('%%%%%'+l2);
system.debug('&&&&&'+doc.toxmlstring());
```

Any help How to remove that. I have seen some article but that is mostly with a specific attributes but not for the entire node.

Thank You !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
Boolean remove = l2.getParent().removeChild(l2);
```

To remove all classifiedvalues nodes:

```
for (Dom.XmlNode child : l1.getChildren()) {
    if (child.getName() == 'classifiedvalues') {
        child.getParent().removeChild(child);
    }
}
```

I think this is not well documented, child needs to be removed from immediate parent.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried that but it actually removed only the first node. How do i remove all the child node with  <classifiedvalues> in the entire xml. I tried with getchildelements under the for loop to iterate  but it didn't work. Any help on that . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this below, hope this is the right way

```
for(Dom.XMLNode node1 :l1.getChildElements()){
Dom.XMLNode l2= l1.getChildElement('classifiedvalues','http://p3.secure.asp/2006/04/data'); 
If(l2 != null){
    Boolean remove = node1.getParent().removeChild(l2);
}
```

Comment: This seems like Murali's answer below - you might consider accepting that answer to show that it solved your issue, if that is the case.

Comment: Yes ofcourse. The second answer is basically to clear the loop xml tag